# How To Use SetState In ExpandablePanel in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, expandable

in **ExpandedPanel** I put two buttons when press on the first change container contant, but setState() doesn't work to change the value of **Scaffold_*Syllabus****  with the value of **Table_Lecture*****_Scaffold**

the code

```
class Syllabus extends StatefulWidget {
  const Syllabus({super.key});

  @override
  State<Syllabus> createState() => _SyllabusState();
}

class _SyllabusState extends State<Syllabus> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size? _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    Container _Scaffold_Syllabus = Container();
    final Color color1 = HexColor('#3E6BA9');
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ExpansionPanelList(
                children: [
                  ExpansionPanel(
                      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                        return Text("dc");
                      },
                      body: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: _size.width > 450
                              ? EdgeInsets.all(40)
                              : EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 3, color: color1)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
// the next code want change the container contant
                                          setState(() {
                                            _Scaffold_Syllabus =
                                                Table_Lectures_Scaffold;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: new Text("ترم أول",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: _size.width <= 435
                                                    ? 9
                                                    : 15)),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          foregroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                                  Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                              ? color1
                                              : Colors.white,
                                          backgroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                                  Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                              ? Colors.white
                                              : color1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _Scaffold_Syllabus =
                                                Table_Lectures_Scaffold;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: new Text("ترم ثان",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: _size.width <= 435
                                                    ? 9
                                                    : 15)),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          foregroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                                  Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                              ? color1
                                              : Colors.white,
                                          backgroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                                  Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                              ? Colors.white
                                              : color1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              SafeArea(
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 500,
                                  height: 500,
                                  padding: _size.width > 450
                                      ? EdgeInsets.all(40)
                                      : EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border:
                                          Border.all(width: 3, color: color1)),
                                  child: _Scaffold_Syllabus,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
              ExpandablePanel(
                  header: Text("منهج السنه الدراسية الرابعة"),
                  collapsed: Text(""),
                  expanded: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: _size.width > 450
                          ? EdgeInsets.all(40)
                          : EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 3, color: color1)),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _Scaffold_Syllabus =
                                            Table_Lectures_Scaffold;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: new Text("ترم أول",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize:
                                                _size.width <= 435 ? 9 : 15)),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      foregroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                              Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                          ? color1
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                              Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                          ? Colors.white
                                          : color1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Center(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _Scaffold_Syllabus =
                                            Table_Lectures_Scaffold;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: new Text("ترم ثان",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize:
                                                _size.width <= 435 ? 9 : 15)),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      foregroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                              Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                          ? color1
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: _Scaffold_Syllabus ==
                                              Table_Lectures_Scaffold
                                          ? Colors.white
                                          : color1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          SafeArea(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 500,
                              height: 500,
                              padding: _size.width > 450
                                  ? EdgeInsets.all(40)
                                  : EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(width: 3, color: color1)),
                              child: _Scaffold_Syllabus,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i try to change the contant of container when i press the button, but setstate doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for asking but, why do you need variable with type of container?
So there's an error that, you are declaring variables in the build method, and when you use setstate, build method is rebuild and your variables stay unchanged. Because they are also redeclared in the build method. Try to declare variables out of build method.
Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
const TestPage({super.key});

@override
State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {

@override
void initState() {
container = Container(color: Colors.black,);
super.initState();
}
Container? _Scaffold_Syllabus=Container(); //Declare variables
here
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: container!),//this container is changed when 
button is pressed
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          container = Container(color: Colors.red,);
          setState(() {});
        }, child: Text("red Container")),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          container = Container(color: Colors.blue,);
          setState(() {});
        }, child: Text("blue Container")),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: in Table_Lectures_Scaffold i put statefulwidget in container  then when i put it in Scaffold_Syllabus the container should change but it doesn't work

Comment: i need it to change the container from bage to another

Comment: okay I understood, my friend I'm saying that, `build` method is rebuild **everytime** when you use `setstate`, so you need to declare variables outside of build method, or on the top of the method.
Just look in the answer where I declared variables. Your PROBLEM is ONLY you DECLARE VARIABLES IN BUILD METHOD AND IT IS WRONG.

Comment: here is another example for you:

    `class _TestPage extends State<TestPage>{

    Container _Scaffold_Syllabus=Container() //Declare variables here


    @override 

    build(BuildContext context){

    return Scaffold();

    }

    }
`

Answer (score 0):

It is primarily because of the wrong logic, i.e

You've established a `Container`type variable named `_Scaffold_Syllabus` in your code and given it an empty `Container`. When the buttons are pressed, you are then setting its value to `Table_Lectures_Scaffold`. But, altering its value will have no impact on the user interface because you are not really utilising `_Scaffold_Syllabus` anywhere in your code.

You must swap out the `Container` widget in your `SafeArea` for `_Scaffold Syllabus` in order to fulfil your goals. Depending on which button is pushed, you should also modify the value of `_Scaffold_Syllabus` to `Scaffold_Syllabus1` or `Scaffold_Syllabus2`.